# How do you globally disable DOM Mouseenter events on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm writing a plugin, I hope I can at some point to ban some dom elements mouseenter events, these dom elements is not my control,  when using the native js, for example

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const test=document.getElementById('test')
    test.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      console.log('test mouseenter')
    })

    document.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()
    }, true)
  </script>
</body>
```

The Mouseenter of the test element no longer works。but in react，it not work。like

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
}, true)
export default () => {
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    console.log('entery');
  }

  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} >
      test
    </div>
  );
}
```

What should I do to achieve the effect of native JS

Comment: React uses javascript, so `document.getElementById('test')` would still work. You probably want to attach an event listener to `document` *after* the component mounts.

Answer (score 0):

React-17 documentation says:

> "When a DOM event fires on the document, React figures out which
> component to call, and then the React event “bubbles” upwards through
> your components. But behind the scenes, the native event has already
> bubbled up to the document level, where React installs its event
> handlers."

If you have multiple React versions on the page, they all register event handlers at the top. This breaks e.stopPropagation(): if a nested tree has stopped propagation of an event, the outer tree would still receive it. This made it difficult to nest different versions of React. This concern is not hypothetical — for example, the Atom editor ran into this four years ago.

In React 16 and earlier, React would do document.addEventListener() for most events. React 17 will call rootNode.addEventListener() under the hood instead.

This resource can be helpful: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html